# Convergence on only some non-tangential limits

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, conformal-geometry

I am interested in the boundary behavior of Riemann maps.  Is there a nice example of a region $G$ with Riemann map $\phi:\mathbb{D}\to G$ such that the limit of $\phi$ exists along some non-tangential paths but not along others?

Specifically, if the limit of $\phi(z)$ exists as $z\to 1$ along any (non-tangential) path above the real axis, but diverges along any path lying below the real axis.

If Riemann maps do not provide a nice example, how about any analytic function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does **not** occur.  For a Riemann map, we may as well assume $G$ is bounded.  If $\phi$ is bounded, and analytic, and the limit of $\phi(z)$ exists along any path approaching $a\in\partial\mathbb{D}$, then immediately all non-tangential limits exist at $a$.  See for example Conway's *Function of One Complex Variable II* page 23.